# How to find location of WAS SystemOut.log in Java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

With a Java servlet in a web application installed on WebSphere Application Server v7 or later, is there a way to determine the file-system directory of the SystemOut.log file, in order to read and write files in that directory?

Note that printing or writing to Java's `System.out` in an app on WAS writes to the SystemOut.log file in every WAS installation I've seen.

I have two use cases for this:

- I want a servlet that can read lines from SystemOut.log and send them to the browser, for the purpose of debugging apps I've developed when the customer won't allow me to access their development server's file-system.
- I want another servlet to create its own log file in the same directory as SystemOut.log, so the app's logs can be retained for a longer period than entries in SystemOut.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the location of `System.out` is determined by `SERVER_LOG_ROOT` variable (see `Environment/WebSphere Variables` in the admin console). Reading the value of WebSphere variable requires the use of MBean and some coding. Here is useful information:

- [WebSphere Variables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/ccws_variable.html)
- [Creating, editing, and deleting WebSphere
  variables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tcws_variable.html)

The location of log files can also be set through `Troubleshooting/Log` and `trace/server/JVM Logs` in the admin console.

Comment: Thanks. The second link provides the relevant code, but it seems it won't serve either of my use-cases, because of the statement that expanding WebSphere variables requires admin privileges.

Comment: WAS uses Java Util Logging under the hood. It should be possible to access the configuration at runtime and read log file location from corresponding handler. Not a clean solution but better than nothing.

Comment: I don't see how to get file locations through `java.util.logging` classes. The various `Handler` classes don't seem to have any method for that. I can access Java System properties and found a `logging.properties` file on a test server, but that doesn't state any file paths. I think WebSphere variables probably override the properties file.